# inserted items disappear from boost::mpl::map

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

The following example demonstrates what I mean:

```
    #include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/insert.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace boost::mpl;

    template <int n1, int n2>
    struct entry
    {
        typedef pair<int_<n1>, int_<n2> > type;
    };

    typedef map<entry<1,1>::type> entries;

    typedef insert<
        entries, entry<4,4>::type>::type update;

    typedef insert<
        update,
        entry<5,5>::type>::type update2;

    struct print_values
    {
        template <class I>
        void operator()(I)
        {
            std::cout << first<I>::type::value << ", " 
                      << second<I>::type::value << std::endl;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        for_each<update2>(print_values());
        std::cout << "Next:" << std::endl;
        for_each<update2::type>(print_values());
    }
```

outputs:

```
    1, 1
    4, 4
    5, 5
    Next:
    1, 1
```

When I evaluate `update2` by accessing `update2::type` the items I inserted disappear.

Why does this happen and what can I do to to make sure the evaluating `update2` doesn't remove the inserted elements?

Answer (score 2):

I'm convinced this is a bug in `boost::mpl`.

The result of inserting an element into an `mpl::map` is not an item of type `mpl::map` but of `mpl::m_item`.  This `m_item` holds the newly inserted key and value as well as the map they were inserted into.
Now every class in `boost::mpl` is a metafunction, containers are a metafunction that return themselves.  This is useful for situations like this

```
    typedef map<pair<int,int> > i_map;
    eval_if<true_,
            i_map,
            at<i_map, float> >::type type;
```

So `mpl::map` has a typedef inside it that is simply `typedef map type;`, `m_item`, however, lacks this `typedef` and so since it derives from the `map` it's inserted into `m_item::type` is actually `map::type`.

This means my example after insertion (dropping the `int_<>` for brevity) looks like:

```
   m_item<5, 5, m_item<4, 4, map1<pair<1, 1> > > >
```

and accessing its type reaches all the way back up to `map1<pair<1, 1> >::type` which returns `map<pair<1, 1> >` which is why all the inserted items are disappearing.

I logged a [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8749) and was originally waiting for a response before posting this answer but after 4 weeks I decided to post this without any answer from them.

The solution is to simply add `typedef m_item type;` to `boost::mpl::m_item` in `boost/mpl/map/aux_/item.hpp`.  This will make `m_item` a metafunction that correctly returns itself and not return the original map.