# How do I insert types into a boost mpl map to get a map as return type?

Tags: c++, boost

Suppose I have `boost mpl` container of types:

```
using boost::mpl;
using Map = map<pair<int, double>>;

// add a pair to the map
using Result = typename insert<Map, pair<double, bool> >::type;

Result result;

// at this point I would expect to have a map<pair<int, double>, pair<double, bool>>
std::cout << boost::units::detail::demangle(typeid(result).name());
```

strangely, the output of this program is

```
m_item<double, bool, map<pair<int, double>, na, na...>
```

A seemingly related issue was posted here some years ago:

[inserted items disappear from boost::mpl::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393496/inserted-items-disappear-from-boostmplmap)

Is this a bug? I'm using `boost 1.56`

Comment: I get similar issues when I simply try to insert values into a `boost::mpl` set; it creates a strange combination of `s_item` objects nested...

Comment: `boost::units::detail::demangle` - what. I admit I didn't know it was there, but why would you use implementation details like this?

Comment: What output do you expect? Why is the output strange? (a.k.a. what are you trying to achieve/what's the XY problem here)

Comment: @sehe I expect the output to be a map, as mentioned in the title.

Comment: @sehe "*`boost::units::detail::demangle` - what. I admit I didn't know it was there, but why would you use implementation details like this?*" I'm not sure what's surprising about this. The function is well documented, and I'm using it for the only purpose anyone is likely to use it for; to see the type being produced.

Comment: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10116 detail headers aren't "well documented" - should in fact not be part of documented interface. I couldn't find it anyways.